# Inserted value is incorrect for insert

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm inserting multiple rows of data, each with two record columns.

The first row inserts correctly (as well as if there is just one row), but all subsequent rows have a single incorrect value (`sell.min`).  It happens to be the first column of the first record.

Query

```sql
INSERT INTO market_data.daily (date, locationId, typeId, typeName, sell, buy, totalVolume) VALUES 
("""2019-04-21""", 60003760, 18837, """Corpum C-Type Energized Explosive Membrane""", 
  (6550027.0, 3.999999993E7, 1.44241181091E7, 8428558.23879, 7456719.34645, 14.0, -1.0), 
  (1006502.65, 1555047.05, 1258968.26415, 247301.248151, 1555047.04377, 13.0, -1.0), 
-1.0), 
("""2019-04-21""", 60003760, 33281, """Capital Drone Durability Enhancer I""", 
  (5.199989895E7, 5.1999999E7, 5.1999973063E7, 57.7494660851, 5.199989895E7, 3.0, -1.0), 
  (5000000.02, 4.199999091E7, 3.05050486484E7, 1.47204376114E7, 4.1999990902E7, 7.0, -1.0),
  -1.0), 
("""2019-04-21""", 60003760, 49979, """'Absolute' Injection Augmentor""", 
  (3000000.0, 9.999999999E7, 6.37555555511E7, 4.87653907276E7, 3000000.0, 3.0, -1.0), 
  (10.01, 10.01, 10.01, 0.01, 10.01, 1.0, -1.0), 
-1.0), 
("""2019-04-21""", 60003760, 18839, """Centum C-Type Energized Explosive Membrane""", 
  (3999999.84, 2.999999996E7, 1.8556233027E7, 6729883.37456, 3999999.84057, 15.0, -1.0), 
  (1006989.98, 3500001.98, 1791680.30288, 936471.377223, 3500001.98, 10.0, -1.0), 
-1.0), 
("""2019-04-21""", 60003760, 14262, """Dark Blood Stasis Webifier""", 
  (1.1069999996E7, 2.4523999696E7, 1.35810174441E7, 3.26196555149E7, 1.10699999963E7, 18.0, -1.0), 
  (97842.98, 1.0179234021E7, 8.88308106524E7, 2.47111060358E7, 1.01792340196E7, 24.0, -1.0),
-1.0);
```

Table Schema

```
date    STRING  REQUIRED    
locationId  INTEGER REQUIRED    
typeId  INTEGER REQUIRED    
typeName    STRING  REQUIRED    
sell    RECORD  REQUIRED    
sell. min   NUMERIC REQUIRED    
sell. max   NUMERIC REQUIRED    
sell. average   NUMERIC REQUIRED    
sell. stdDev    NUMERIC REQUIRED    
sell. percentile    NUMERIC REQUIRED    
sell. orderCount    NUMERIC REQUIRED    
sell. volume    NUMERIC NULLABLE    
buy RECORD  REQUIRED    
buy. min    NUMERIC REQUIRED    
buy. max    NUMERIC REQUIRED    
buy. average    NUMERIC REQUIRED    
buy. stdDev NUMERIC REQUIRED    
buy. percentile NUMERIC REQUIRED    
buy. orderCount NUMERIC REQUIRED    
buy. volume NUMERIC NULLABLE    
totalVolume NUMERIC NULLABLE
```

[Result](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MutFnnSS8TXJwFu89ZkRg-9paOD7QuShBEBkwOZ_tHk/edit?usp=sharing)

[Picture of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPfyQ.png)

`sell.min` values except for the first one are low values that have no relation to anything else in the query, as far as I can tell.  They aren't always ints.

This happens when executing the query from the web UI or the Java API.

Comment: Hey rnett, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include all relevant information in the question itself. Outside links can break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below instead

```
#standardSQL
INSERT INTO market_data.daily (date, locationId, typeId, typeName, sell, buy, totalVolume) VALUES 
("""2019-04-21""", 60003760, 18837, """Corpum C-Type Energized Explosive Membrane""", 
  STRUCT<min NUMERIC, max NUMERIC, average NUMERIC, stdDev NUMERIC, percentile NUMERIC, orderCount NUMERIC, volume  NUMERIC>(6550027.0, 3.999999993E7, 1.44241181091E7, 8428558.23879, 7456719.34645, 14.0, -1.0), 
  STRUCT<min NUMERIC, max NUMERIC, average NUMERIC, stdDev NUMERIC, percentile NUMERIC, orderCount NUMERIC, volume  NUMERIC>(1006502.65, 1555047.05, 1258968.26415, 247301.248151, 1555047.04377, 13.0, -1.0), 
-1.0), 
("""2019-04-21""", 60003760, 33281, """Capital Drone Durability Enhancer I""", 
  STRUCT<min NUMERIC, max NUMERIC, average NUMERIC, stdDev NUMERIC, percentile NUMERIC, orderCount NUMERIC, volume  NUMERIC>(5.199989895E7, 5.1999999E7, 5.1999973063E7, 57.7494660851, 5.199989895E7, 3.0, -1.0), 
  STRUCT<min NUMERIC, max NUMERIC, average NUMERIC, stdDev NUMERIC, percentile NUMERIC, orderCount NUMERIC, volume  NUMERIC>(5000000.02, 4.199999091E7, 3.05050486484E7, 1.47204376114E7, 4.1999990902E7, 7.0, -1.0),
  -1.0), 
("""2019-04-21""", 60003760, 49979, """'Absolute' Injection Augmentor""", 
  STRUCT<min NUMERIC, max NUMERIC, average NUMERIC, stdDev NUMERIC, percentile NUMERIC, orderCount NUMERIC, volume  NUMERIC>(3000000.0, 9.999999999E7, 6.37555555511E7, 4.87653907276E7, 3000000.0, 3.0, -1.0), 
  STRUCT<min NUMERIC, max NUMERIC, average NUMERIC, stdDev NUMERIC, percentile NUMERIC, orderCount NUMERIC, volume  NUMERIC>(10.01, 10.01, 10.01, 0.01, 10.01, 1.0, -1.0), 
-1.0), 
("""2019-04-21""", 60003760, 18839, """Centum C-Type Energized Explosive Membrane""", 
  STRUCT<min NUMERIC, max NUMERIC, average NUMERIC, stdDev NUMERIC, percentile NUMERIC, orderCount NUMERIC, volume  NUMERIC>(3999999.84, 2.999999996E7, 1.8556233027E7, 6729883.37456, 3999999.84057, 15.0, -1.0), 
  STRUCT<min NUMERIC, max NUMERIC, average NUMERIC, stdDev NUMERIC, percentile NUMERIC, orderCount NUMERIC, volume  NUMERIC>(1006989.98, 3500001.98, 1791680.30288, 936471.377223, 3500001.98, 10.0, -1.0), 
-1.0), 
("""2019-04-21""", 60003760, 14262, """Dark Blood Stasis Webifier""", 
  STRUCT<min NUMERIC, max NUMERIC, average NUMERIC, stdDev NUMERIC, percentile NUMERIC, orderCount NUMERIC, volume  NUMERIC>(1.1069999996E7, 2.4523999696E7, 1.35810174441E7, 3.26196555149E7, 1.10699999963E7, 18.0, -1.0), 
  STRUCT<min NUMERIC, max NUMERIC, average NUMERIC, stdDev NUMERIC, percentile NUMERIC, orderCount NUMERIC, volume  NUMERIC>(97842.98, 1.0179234021E7, 8.88308106524E7, 2.47111060358E7, 1.01792340196E7, 24.0, -1.0),
-1.0);
```

This is quick and "dirty" trick should let you go forward with your inserts

As you can see - here - I just added explicit fields definition

```
STRUCT<min NUMERIC, max NUMERIC, average NUMERIC, stdDev NUMERIC, percentile NUMERIC, orderCount NUMERIC, volume  NUMERIC>
```